# Rails authentication with boolean attribute (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

How do I use a `before_filter` to authenticate a boolean attribute in my User model? For example, If my User has a boolean attribute `:lender` that is equal to true, and I would like only lenders to view a certain page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise has a builtin helper, :authenticate_user!, that you can use to make sure the user is logged in. Then, you can add another before_filter to check for the condition you want, redirecting/rendering an error page if the user isn't allowed to view that page.

```
class PagesController < ActionController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    before_filter :check_lender, :only => [<pages_to_allow>]

    private
        def check_lender
            render 'errors/access_not_permitted' unless current_user.lender?
        end
```

Comment: Thanks! You've just saved StackOverflow from duplicating question :)

Answer (score 1):

In the controller that is serving up the page in question, create a custom method that checks to make sure the current user is a lender, then call that method in your before_action. For example:

```
class WidgetsController < ActionController
  before_action :ensure_lender, only: [:show]

  private

  def ensure_lender
    current_user.lender
  end
end
```

This solution assumes you have a current_user method defined elsewhere (i.e. the ApplicationController), which returns a user object for the currently logged in user.